# Fragment seems to inflate wrong view

Tags: android-fragments

I'm currently trying to program an `Android Launcher` with `Fragments` but I have problems with the `Views` on the `Fragments`.
I have a `Dock-Fragmen`t with a `Dock-Controller` which allow the user to change fragments, such as apps menu, settings fragment etc. The `Dock` is displayed on the buttom of the display, the `Fragments`(apps menu, settings fragment) should be displayed above the `Dock`.
The problem is, that the apps menu is not shown in its associated `Fragment` but rather in the `Dock Fragment` behind the dock icons,... So I guess, the app menu fragment gets the wrong view in its `onCreateView()`-Method, but I don't get why.

This is the code of the `MainActivity` that extends from `FragmentActivity`. I add the fragments to the manager.

```
private void addDockToManager() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(dbConnection.getLayout(DOCK_TAG), dockController.getFragment(), DOCK_TAG);
    ft.commit();
}

private void addPluginsToManager() {
    FragmentManager fm = null;
    FragmentTransaction ft = null;

    for(String key : controllerMap.keySet()) {
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        FrameController controller = null;

        if ((controller = controllerMap.get(key)) != null) {
            ft.add(dbConnection.getLayout(key), controller.getFragment(), key);

            if (key.equals(standardFrame))
                ft.addToBackStack(key);
        }
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }


    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    for(String key : controllerMap.keySet()) {          
        if (controllerMap.get(key) != null && !key.equals(standardFrame)) {
            ft.hide(fm.findFragmentByTag(key));
        }
    }
    ft.commit();

}
```

The layouts are hardcoded at the moment in `dbConnection`:

```
public int getLayout(String name) {
    int layout = -1;

    switch(name) {
        case "app_menu" : layout = R.id.fl_app_menu;
        case "settings" : layout = R.id.fl_settings;
        case "dock" : layout = R.id.fl_dock;
    }

    return layout;
}
```

The `MainActivity's` xml looks like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.activity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fl_dock"
        android:background="#00ffffff" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_app_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fl_dock"
        android:background="#00ffffff" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_dock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml of the apps menu is a `gridview` and looks like that:

```
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gv_apps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >


</GridView>
```

The `App Fragment` looks like that:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.external_apps, group, false);
    layout = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv_apps);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter((AppMenuController) myController, apps);
   ((GridView) layout).setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
}
```

And the `getView` Method of the `GridViewAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(controller.getMainActivity().getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageDrawable(buttons.get(position).getIcon());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(65, 65));
    return imageView;
}
```

I hope what I mentioned is enough to resolve the problem. I am searching the web for hours but I found no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a much simpler problem than that I think.

```
public int getLayout(String name) {
    int layout = -1;

    switch(name) {
        case "app_menu" : layout = R.id.fl_app_menu;
        case "settings" : layout = R.id.fl_settings;
        case "dock" : layout = R.id.fl_dock;
    }

    return layout;
}
```

Should be:

```
public int getLayout(String name) {
    int layout = -1;

    switch(name) {
        case "app_menu" : 
          layout = R.id.fl_app_menu;
          break;
        case "settings" : 
          layout = R.id.fl_settings;
          break;
        case "dock" : 
          layout = R.id.fl_dock;
          break;
    }
    return layout;
}
```

Because switch-case structure is still essentially just an organized goto, and not actually an if-else structure, aka if you don't break out, then all cases will run sequentially.

Comment: Haha, no problem :P It happens to me too, which is why I rather use if-elseif-else structures instead, even if people say switches are "prettier" :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. And it was in a part of the code I never expected it to be.

The Dummy-Switch-Case in dbConnection caused it. Seemingly Strings aren't compared by value but rather by reference in such a Switch-Case. So it always chose the dock container layout to be associated with the app menu in the fragment manager,...

Comment: No, I think the problem is that there is no "break" statement after each case in the switch.